# System.Threading.Thread não existe?

Tags: c#

Estou tentando aprender a usar multithreading em C#, mas todos os tutoriais pedem para eu usar a classe System.Threading.Thread, mas parece que no meu Visual Studio essa classe não existe! Um print pra vocês entenderem melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu to esquecendo de alguma coisa? Preciso fazer alguma configuração? Eu sou meio novo no c#, mas eu já costumava mecher em Threads no java

Comment: Que tipo de aplicação? Xaml? Windows Forms? Se for XAML tente importar referência `System.Threading.dll`

Comment: estou usando uma Framework chamada Duality2D, para desenvolvimento de jogos, que integra o Visual Studio direto (como no unity), não sei exatamente qual o tipo de aplicação :/

Comment: Pra utilizar os recursos do .NETFramework você precisa importar a referência que você precisa. Mas não creio que um desenvolvimento de um jogo 2D igual ao unity precise dos recursos do framework!

Comment: E então por que não usar a própria Unity2D? É gratuita e tem os mesmos recursos!

Comment: Mas uma dica eu recomendo o uso do MonoDevelop pra Unity e não o Visual Studio 2015, por simplesmente o MonoDevelop tem muito mais recursos pra trabalho na Unity

Answer (score 1):

O `System.Threading.Thread` é definido no mscorlib que é uma DLL padrão para todo projeto em .NET, mas pelo o que você disse nos comentários da pergunta, você aparentemente não está trabalhando num projeto que faz uso do framework .NET.

Se você estiver procurando aprender sobre multi-threading utilizando o `System.Threading.Thread` será necessário utilizar um outro template de projeto do Visual Studio, como os de aplicações para console, Windows Forms e WPF, por exemplo.